# Starting at a specific index in each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slice

Please take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ56N/2/)

How can I use `slice` in the loop to make it return results starting from a specific index?

The JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "title": "A",
    "link": "google.com",
    "image": "image.com",
    "price": "$1295.00",
    "brand": "ABC",
    "color": "Black",
    "material": "Rubber"
  }
]
```

I want it to return results starting from `brand`:

```
brand - ABC

color - Black

material - Rubber
```

I don't know where to put `.slice(4)` in the loop. I got undefined error using
    `$.each(value.slice(4),function(key, value)`

Here's the code:

JS:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%20%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2FaZgYDB%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=",
        success: function (data) {
            var item_html="";
            $(data.query.results.json).each(function(key, value) {
              $.each(value,function(key, value){                             
               item_html += '<h3>'+key+' - '+value+'</h3>';                        
              });
            });            

           $('#area').append(item_html);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Elements of objects are not ordered in Javascript. Only arrays are ordered.

Comment: If you know which keys you want, why don't you just use the names?

Comment: @cookiemonster I have more than 80 objects in each item, and I don't need the first 10 objects in the code, so I was just curious to see if there was a shorter way than using if condition to exclude the first 10 objects.

Comment: Define the keys you want in an Array, and iterate the array using each member to grab the values from the object. `$.each(array_of_keys, function(key) { console.log(key, value[key]); })` But no, as the answer below states, there's no way to do that. You need explicit lists of keys to match or avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Use a separate array of property names, so you can slice it and get the names in a guaranteed order.

```
var props = [
    "title",
    "link",
    "image",
    "price",
    "brand",
    "color",
    "material"
    ];

$.ajax({
    url: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%20%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2FaZgYDB%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var item_html="";
        var propslice = props.slice(4);
        $.each(data.query.results.json, function(i, obj) {
            $.each(propslice, function(i, key) {
                value = obj[key];
                item_html += '<h3>'+key+' - '+value+'</h3>';
            });
        });
        $('#area').append(item_html);
    }
});
```

If there are a small number of properties you want to skip, you can make a list of them in an object, and test against that list:

```
var excluded_props = {
    title: true,
    link: true,
    image: true,
    price: true
};

$.ajax({
    url: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%20%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2FaZgYDB%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var item_html="";
        $.each(data.query.results.json, function(i, obj) {
            $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                if (!excluded_props[key]) {
                    value = obj[key];
                    item_html += '<h3>'+key+' - '+value+'</h3>';
                }
            });
        });
        $('#area').append(item_html);
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 ...or just skip the slice and define `props` to represent the desired subset. Though having the full set may prove useful in other parts of the code. Don't forget your `var` before `value`. :-)

Comment: I assumed that different parts of the code would want to start at a different place. But if not, that's better.

Comment: @Barmar I have trouble getting your second code to work in the fiddle. `propslice` is undefined so I've removed it, but it still isn't working.  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ56N/17/). I got this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '0' in A`

Comment: I just tried it (with your correction -- thx) and it worked for me.

Comment: You need `dataType: 'json'` to get jQuery to parse the JSON response automatically.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for isn't possible with an object.  Objects in Javascript are not ordered, only arrays. You have a few options:

- Refactor your object to be an array
- Refactor your object so that each key has a new key for order*
- loop through each property of the object, placing it into an array (no guaranteed order!) and then looping through the array.

*Example:

```
[
  {
    "title": {
        "value" : "A",
        "order" : 4
    },
    "link": {
        "value" : "google.com",
        "order" : 5
    ...
  }
]
```

Comment: Another option is to have a separate array of property names, in the order that you want them. Then slice that array and use its elements as the keys in the object.

Comment: *"...so that each key has a new key for order"* Could you explain what you mean by that? I'm not understanding what you mean.

Comment: ah, I see. Have a separate key in each object which defines its position. I'd call that a last resort. I think he just wants to exclude a subset of values.